# How to get a list of the transactions that finished today from the finished date on items that are part of a transaction in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
Transaction No.  Item   Finished Date
    1             1       01/1/2016
    1             2       12/5/2016
    1             3       28/5/2016 
    2             1       12/5/2016 
    3             1       01/4/2016
    3             2       18/5/2016
```

From the above list I would only want to return Transaction No. 3 as
that is the only one that finished today.

Comment: You'll need to show us some code and go into the details a bit more.

Comment: I have built a controller that is made up of objects that are items of transactions. Each transaction may have 1 to as many items as required each one having a finished date against it. I want to find out which transaction finished today, so in effect get the max date of the items in the transaction and if that is today it passes the test.

Comment: From what I understood you need a simple function that loops over this array of transactions and checks whether the date is equal to today's date, am I right? How is this related to Angular though?

Comment: I have approached this in a different way, looking at your comment and the data I have been overcomplicating things, I am working on this as my first app in angularjs, thanks a lot.